# Why my table view animation is so strange in Xcode 9?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, ios-simulator, xcode9

I have a `table view` and `basic cells` in `Xcode 9`. When I run the app on a simulator the table view has a quite strange animation. Some of its rows are missing, and when I scroll the view they appear, but now other rows disappear. That is something new, because in `Xcode 8` everything was working just fine. Any suggestions? 
Here how it looks like:[image: strange behaviour of a table view]

Comment: Resize your simulator to full size

Comment: I have already done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 9 "Interface Builder" supports setting the estimatedRowHeight of UITableView. This allows self-sizing table cells by setting the estimated height to a value other than zero, and is on by default.

So basically, you must turn that functionality off to have static cell size. (IB -> select tableview -> Size Inspector)

[image: Selected tableview in IB]

Also if this doesn't work you can always set programatically:

```
tableView.rowHeight = "defined height"
```

Comment: I've tried to uncheck the automatic Row Height and automatic Estimate from the size inspector but it didn't change anything. Could you tell me where is it exactly in the storyboard?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped. But I think there is an issue with the simulator (how it shows table views) because nothing changes there, but when I run on a physical device (even with empty rows), it looks ok. Have you had this kind of problem?

Comment: Try cleaning all your simulator data located in (your HD)/Library/Developer/XCode. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I think this is a simulator's issue, because when I run it on an actual device, everything looks nice.